# why does each plot command (i.e. labels,title) start a new plot in spyder instead of appearing on one graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I'm trying to plot graphs in spyder but every line in my code starts a new plot. I've tried using the example from one of the python tutorials whose code I'm including and the same happens.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3]
y = [5,7,4]

x2 = [1,2,3]
y2 = [10,14,12]

plt.plot(x, y, label='First Line')
plt.plot(x2, y2, label='Second Line')

plt.xlabel('Plot Number')
plt.ylabel('Important var')
plt.title('Interesting Graph\nCheck it out')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Each line produces a new plot instead of adding to the first one. So plt.xlabel gives a new empty plot with an x label instead of adding an x label to the original plot, plt.ylabel does the same and so on.

This is probably a stupid question but I'd really appreciate any help.[picture of plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63OUq.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create an **unique axis** and then add the plots to that axis.

You can do it by creating **subplots**. Try with this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data:
x = [1,2,3]
y = [5,7,4]

x2 = [1,2,3]
y2 = [10,14,12]

# Figure creation:
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x,  y,  label = 'First Line' )
ax.plot(x2, y2, label = 'Second Line')

ax.set_xlabel('Plot Number',  fontsize = 12)
ax.set_ylabel('Important var', fontsize = 12)
ax.set_title('Interesting Graph\nCheck it out', fontsize = 12)

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

If you would like to create two axis, you could do it this way:

`fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)`

And then add the plot to its axis on an independent way.

```
ax1.plot(x,  y,  label = 'First Line' )
ax2.plot(x2, y2, label = 'Second Line')
```

Comment: Thanks! This is giving me the one plot

Answer (score 1):

Your code works correctly for me.

[image: My result]

Comment: Sorry, thanks for answering. It's a stupid mistake I'm making. My friend pointed out that I wasn't running the code together but each line individually so I was getting separate plots.

Comment: @saxonryan, why is running the commands separately cause issues?